# How to prevent PVC from being deleted in K8s

Tags: kubernetes

I recently encountered an issue where something (which I was not able to identify) deleted a PVC and the corresponding PV in my k8s cluster. The data can be recovered but I have two questions:

1. Is there some hack to prevent the PVC from being deleted accidentally if someone issues a wrong command which deletes it?
2. Is it possible to check what command caused the deletion of the PVC via some logs?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#storage-object-in-use-protection

Answer (score 4):

For question 1, you can set the Reclaim Policy to `Retain`. This means that the PV and PVC can be deleted but the underlying storage volume will stick around forever (or until you delete it in whatever the underlying system is).

For 2, yes if you have audit logging turned on. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/#audit-backends. Otherwise not really.

Comment: A Retain reclaimPolicy won't help if you delete the PV object. It would only ensure that when deleting a PVC, the corresponding PV would remain. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/#why-change-reclaim-policy-of-a-persistentvolume

Comment: I believe it applies at both levels https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#retain but I don't have a cluster handy to test with.